# RegEx for matching a pattern in query strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have some code that will create a query string and loop through and check the query strings.

```
$pi = An ip defined
$bo = The content of a file.
```

I am searching within the `$bo` and looking for the `$pi` and I want to print out ALL lines that match that string but I am having some issues with printing out certain lines from the `$bo`.

This is what's include in `$bo`:

```
if (strstr($bo, $pi)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . preg_match($ip, $body) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general pattern you may use for an entire line which contains the `$ip` string:

```
$pattern = '/^.*\b' . $ip . '\b.*$/m';
```

Then, we can use this pattern with `preg_match_all` to find all matching lines:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $body, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim - I am receiving an Array to string conversion error with the current setup - Does it have to be an array when echo'ing lines?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `preg_grep()` instead of `preg_match()` because it directly returns only the matches and doesn't require building a pattern to capture the line. However, it does require the input to be an array of lines from the file, which you can easily do via `file()` or `explode()`:

```
// Read a file directly into an array.
$body = file('/path/to/file');

// Or split an existing big string into an array of lines.
$body = explode("\n", $fileContents);

foreach (preg_grep($ip, $body) as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Or just:

```
echo implode("\n", preg_grep($ip, $body));
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Alex, I am receiving an strstr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in error which I am trying to tackle.

Comment: You don't need that `strstr()` check, just skip it. You're basically saying, "If the text contains the IP then look for the IP in the text." It's redundant.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I went ahead and played around with it and removed it - I'm receiving a `preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given` error on: `echo "<td><PRE>" . implode("\n", preg_grep($ip, $body)) . "</PRE></td>";`